# multiple instances of the same object spaced out using a loop is only creating one

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, instantiation

I had a hard time trying to word my question properly, so i'm sorry if it seems confusing. Also i'm using the flixel library in flash builder. It may not be that important butcause probably anyone that knows a little more than me or even a little AS3 could probably see what i'm doing wrong.

Anyway, what i'm trying to do is basically create 10 instances of this square object I made. all I have to do is pass it an x an y coordinate to place it and it works. so ive tested if i just do:

```
var testsquare:Bgsq;
testsquare = new Bgsq(0,0);
add(testsquare);
```

it works fine and adds a square at 0,0 just like i told it to, but i want to add 10 of them then move the next one that's created 25 px to the right (because each square is 25px)

my problem is that I only ever see 1 square, like it's only making 1 instance of it still.

anyone possibly have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
var counter:int = 0;
var bgsqa:Array = new Array;

for (var ibgs:int = 0; ibgs < 10; ibgs++)
    {
    bgsqa[counter] = new Bgsq(0,0);
    bgsqa[counter].x += 25;
    add(bgsqa[counter]);
    counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot you're doing wrong here.

First off, you're using a pseudo-iterator (counter) to access array elements through a loop instead of, well, using the iterator (ibgs).

Second, I don't see anything in the array (bgsqa) you're iterating through. It's no wonder you're having problems. Here's what you should do.

```
var bgsqa:Array = [];
for(var i:int=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var bgsq:Bgsq = new Bgsq(i * 25, 0);
    add(bgsq);
    bgsqa.push(bgsq);
}
```

That should probably do it if your post is accurate.

Comment: i see what you're saying for the counter, ill fix that. But wont that just keep moving the square "bgsq" over 25 pixels so when it loads I only actually see the 10th one created? I need to have 10 separate squares that are all created 25 pixels apart

Comment: When you loop like this, you're adding a new item every time. Each item has been inserted into an array that exists at a scope outside of the loop, so you can access all of them after the loop completes.

Comment: nvm, i got it! using my array code while not using an "outside" counter did it! thank you for helping me realize that! duh.

Comment: Mark my answer as the answer if you've figured it out. What you just posted is essentially the code I posted not a few minutes earlier.

Comment: i was going to it looked like you left out the array part. is it not nessisary to use the [ibgs]next to the array? that's the only reason i didnt mark it as the answer because that part was nessiary and i didnt want confusion. but if it would work without using the [] then yeah ill delete mine and mark urs as the answer

Comment: You're trying to access something in an array that doesn't exist. The array is empty. Just use the `bgsq` variable to edit properties inside the loop and then use a separate for loop to handle all the boxes inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

for (var ibgs:int = 0; ibgs < 10; ibgs++)

```
{
bgsqa[counter] = new Bgsq(0,0);
bgsqa[counter].x = counter * 25;
add(bgsqa[counter]);
counter++;
}
```

They start at 0, so applying `+=` is simply adding 25 to 0.  This should do the trick.

Comment: well, the first one should be placed on 0,0 then the second on (25,0) the point of the counter variable was to represent a new instance name so there can be multiple copies of the same opbject so it doesnt just keep moving the original object